# How to check if a TextView contains a certain string

Tags: java, android, string

Hi I want to add an if statement that checks to see if a text in a textview (called TextView1) contains a ".". I know I can check to see if the text equals ".". But I dont know how to check if the text contains a ".". Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

I dont know what to do to TextArea1 to check if it contains a decimal point

```
if (TextArea1      ){
    //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
if(TextArea1.getText().toString().contains("."))
```

Comment: Thanks! Dont know why I have negative votes, its a genuine question

Comment: Most probably because it shows no research effort on your part.

Comment: what if I want to check string has @,#,$, any of them

Answer (score 0):

For String you can just to the following:

```
String text = "Z Hello";

if(text.contains("Z"){
 // Yes
}
```